# Meteor: Random.fraction() issue

Tags: meteor

I'm getting the following error when after installing my Meteor app (developed on an older version of Meteor) on Meteor version 1.2.0.1:

`ReferenceError: Random is not defined`

Offending line:

```
Players.insert({name: names[i], score: Math.floor(Random.fraction()*10)*5});
```

I've never had a problem with this line of code before and according to the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random) this should still work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got to install the `random` package, it's not installed by default anymore. A simple `meteor add random` will suffice.

Comment: Thank you, looks like I've got a lot to catch up with using Meteor!

Answer (score 3):

Some basic packages were removed from Meteor to reduce its initial footprint.  Perhaps if you run `meteor add random` your issue will be solved.  The update process was supposed to detect your use of `Random` and automatically install the package but perhaps it slipped through.

If you are working inside of a package, you may need to add `random@1.0.4` to your `api.use()`.

For a list of packages that are no longer installed by default, see this link: https://quip.com/RXFlAk9Rc2xI .  It also contains some other interesting notes about the update.